# want to convert my webapp to desktop app with data persistence

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-webkit, nwjs

I have created a payroll webapp and have used mysql and node js to build it.
The problem is that I am not sure how to convert it to a desktop webapp.
I have used the node-mysql module for this, so do I need to change something now
or just convert it using node webkit?

How does this work, really?

Here's what my server.js looks like now. so , do I need to make any changes to the code again?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
//var ejsLint=require('./server.js');
//ejsLint.lint('attendance-data.ejs', '-p');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'employees',
    multipleStatements:true
});

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function (req,res){
    res.render('index');
});
var daValue=227.30;
app.get('/da',function(req,res){
    res.render('da');
});
app.post('/da-data',function(req,res){
    daValue = Number(req.body.da);
        var data = {da :daValue};
           console.log('da is :',daValue);

    res.render('da-data.ejs',data);
});

app.get('/add-employee',function(req,res){
    res.render('add-employee');
});

app.post('/add-employee',function(req,res){
    res.status(200).send();
    console.log('employee '+req.body.name + ' added');
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});

app.post('/form',function (req,res){
    //employee details from add-employee.html page
var name=req.body.name;
var designation = req.body.designation;
var pan = req.body.pan;
var aadhar = req.body.aadhar;
var bank = req.body.bank;
var basicSalary = req.body.salary;
var allowance = req.body.allowance;
var grossSalary = req.body.salarygross;
var esi = req.body.esi;
var uan = req.body.uan;


var details = {name:name,designation:designation,pan:pan,aadhar:aadhar,
    bank:bank,basic_salary:basicSalary,other_allowances:allowance,gross_salary:grossSalary,esi:esi,uan:uan};
    // for sending data as objects into database
    // use {name of database column : name of the variable where it's value is stored}
    // example {wages_rate is the name of database column : wagesRate is the variable where
        // value is stored}

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO employee_details SET ?',details,function(err,result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(query.sql);
}); 

res.status(200).send('employee ' + name + 'with salary of '+salary+ ' added');

});

app.get('/show',function (req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee_details',function(err,rows){
  if(err) throw err;

  console.log('Data received');
  console.log(rows);
   var data ="Id "+"<strong>" +" name "+" designation "+" uan"+"</strong>";
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    data = data+"<br>" + (i+1)+". "+rows[i].name +" "+rows[i].designation+" "+rows[i].uan+"<br>";
  }

 res.send(data);
});
});

     var rowsLength;
     var salaryFromRow;
     var salaryArr=[];
     var allowanceFromRow;

     var allowanceArr=[];
     var designationArr=[];
app.get('/attendance',function (req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee_details',function(err,rows){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
   }else{
      rowsLength = rows.length;

     for(var i=0;i<rowsLength;i++){
        salaryFromRow = rows[i].salary;
        salaryArr.push(salaryFromRow);
        allowanceFromRow = rows[i].allowance;
        allowanceArr.push(allowanceFromRow);
        designationArr.push(rows[i].designation);
        console.log('designation is ',designationArr);
     }





    res.render('attendance',{rows:rows});
   }


});
});


app.post('/attendance-data',function(req,res){
    var uanFromHtml;

    var nameFromHtml;

    var  daysPresent;
    var attendance;
    var nameForm;
    var designation;
    var monthFromHTML;
    var t;
    var realBasicSalary;
    var realOtherAllowances;
    var realGrossSalary;
    var pfBasic;
    var esiGross;
    var pTax=0;
    var netAmount;
    var advance=0;
    var finalData = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=rowsLength;i++){
        var dataArr = [];
        var finalTable = [];

        attendance = "attendance"+i;
        t=i-1;
        salaryForPerson = salaryArr[i];
        allowanceForPerson = allowanceArr[i];
        console.log('req.body is ', req.body);


        daysPresent = Number(req.body[attendance]);
        nameFromHtml = req.body.name[t];
        var nameArr = req.body.name;
        uanFromHtml = req.body.uan[t];
        monthFromHTML = req.body.monthyear;

        var uanArr = req.body.uan;
        realBasicSalary = Math.ceil((req.body.basicsalary[t])*(daysPresent/30)) ;
        realOtherAllowances = Math.ceil((req.body.otherallowance[t])*(daysPresent/30));
        realGrossSalary = Math.ceil((req.body.grosssalary[t])*(daysPresent/30));
            console.log('realBasicSalary is '+realBasicSalary+' and realGrossSalary is  '+realGrossSalary+' and realOtherAllowances is '+ realOtherAllowances);
        pfBasic = Math.ceil((12/100)*realBasicSalary);
        esiGross = Math.ceil((1.75/100)*realGrossSalary);

        if(realBasicSalary>10000 && realBasicSalary<=15000){
            pTax = 110;
        }else if(realBasicSalary>=15001 && realBasicSalary<=25000){
            pTax = 130;
        }else if(realBasicSalary>=25001 && realBasicSalary<=40000){
            pTax = 150;
        }else if(realBasicSalary>=40001){
            pTax = 200;
        }
            netAmount = realGrossSalary - (pTax + pfBasic + esiGross + advance);

        console.log('realGrossSalary is '+realGrossSalary + ' and realBasicSalary is '+realBasicSalary+
            'pTax is '+ pTax+ 'pfBasic is '+pfBasic +'esiGross is '+esiGross);

        console.log('namefromhtml is : ', nameFromHtml);
        console.log('attendance is :',attendance);
        console.log('days present is :',daysPresent);
        console.log('monthyear is : ',monthFromHTML);
        dataArr.push(monthFromHTML,uanFromHtml,nameFromHtml,daysPresent,realBasicSalary,realOtherAllowances,realGrossSalary,pTax);

        finalData.push(dataArr);
    /*  uanArr.push(uanFromHtml);
        nameArr.push(nameFromHtml);
        daysArray.push(daysPresent);
        */

        console.log('dataArr is : ',dataArr);
        console.log('finalData is  : ',finalData);

    }
        var attendanceData = {monthyear :monthFromHTML,rows:rowsLength,uanarr:uanArr,designationarr:designationArr,
        namearr:nameArr,finaldata:finalData,realbasicsalary:realBasicSalary,realgrosssalary:realGrossSalary,ptax:pTax,advance:advance};

    connection.query("INSERT INTO attendance_details(month_year,uan,name,days_present,real_basic_salary,other_allowances,gross_salary,ptax) VALUES ?", 
        [finalData], function(err) {
    if (err){
     var errors = err;
     console.log(errors);
     res.send(errors);
 }else{


    //put database query for inserting values here
    res.render('attendance-data.ejs', attendanceData);
 }

});

});

/*
app.get('/final',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT name,designation,salary,wages_rate FROM employee_details;SELECT uan,da,days_present,total_wages FROM attendance_details;',function(err,rows){
    if(err){
        console.error('MySQL — Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    }else{
        var rowsNumber = rows.length;
      console.log('rows is :',rows);
    var nameFinal;
    var designationFinal;
    var salaryFinal;
    var wagesrateFinal;
    var uanFinal;
    var daFinal;
    var daysFinal;
    var totalwagesFinal;
    var nameFinalarr = [];
    var designationFinalarr =[];
    var salaryFinalarr = [];
    var wagesrateFinalarr =[];
    var uanFinalarr =[];
    var daFinalarr =[];
    var daysFinalarr = [];
    var totalwagesFinalarr =[];



    for(var i=0;i<rowsNumber;i++){
        nameFinalarr.push(rows[i].name);
        designationFinalarr.push(rows[i].designation);
        salaryFinalarr.push(rows[i].salary);
        wagesrateFinalarr.push(rows[i].wages_rate);
        uanFinalarr.push(rows[i].uan);
        daysFinalarr.push(rows[i].da);
        daysFinalarr.push(rows[i].days_present);
        totalwagesFinalarr.push(rows[i].total_wages);

    }
        console.log('nameFinalarr is :', nameFinalarr);
        console.log('daysFinalarr is :', daysFinalarr);
    }

    res.render('final',{rows:rowsNumber,name:nameFinal,designation:designationFinal,salary:salaryFinal,wagesrate:wagesrateFinal,uan:uanFinal,da:daFinal,
        days:daysFinal,
        totalwages:totalwagesFinal});
  });

});
*/

app.get('/select-month',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT month_year,name FROM attendance_details',function(err,rows){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{

            var rowsLength = rows.length;
            console.log('rows is ',rows);

            res.render('select-month.ejs',{rows:rows});
        }
    });


});

app.get('/salary-sheet',function(req,res){
    var month = req.query.selectpicker;
    var employeeName = req.query.selectpicker2;
    console.log('employeeName is ',employeeName);
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM attendance_details WHERE month_year='+"'"+month+"' AND name='"+employeeName+"'",function(err,rows){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            var rowsLength = rows.length;
            console.log('rows is ',rows);
            var uanarr=[];
            var namearr=[];
            var daysarr=[];
            var realBasicSalaryarr=[];
            var realOtherAllowancesarr=[];
            var grossSalaryarr=[];
            var ptaxarr=[];
            var advance=0;
            for(var i=0;i<rowsLength;i++){
                uanarr.push(rows[i].uan);
                namearr.push(rows[i].name);
                daysarr.push(rows[i].days_present);
                realBasicSalaryarr.push(rows[i].real_basic_salary);
                realOtherAllowancesarr.push(rows[i].other_allowances);
                grossSalaryarr.push(rows[i].gross_salary);
                ptaxarr.push(rows[i].ptax);

            }
            console.log('realBasicSalaryarr is ',realBasicSalaryarr);
            console.log('namearr is ',namearr);
            res.render('salary-sheet.ejs',{advance:advance,rows:rows,monthyear:month,uanarr:uanarr,namearr:namearr,daysarr:daysarr,basicsalaryarr:realBasicSalaryarr,
                realotherallowancesarr:realOtherAllowancesarr,realgrosssalaryarr:grossSalaryarr,ptaxarr:ptaxarr});
        }
    });


});



app.get('/add-company',function(req,res){
     res.render('add-company.ejs');
});

app.get('/style.css',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/style.css'));
});

app.get('/main.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/main.js'));
});

app.get('/cmain.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/cmain.js'));
});

var port=8080;
app.listen(8080,function(req,res){
   console.log(`Payroll app listening on port ${port}!` );
});
```

Could you tell me how to convert this to a desktop app?

Comment: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/save-persistent-data-in-app

Comment: The challenge with MySQL is that it needs to be running on the target machine, or on the network, if you want it to work as a desktop application.  Do you need this desktop app to run independently of your server, or do you actually just need to wrap your web app so that it "looks" like a desktop app?  In other words, do you want to create a more traditional web app that is standalone?

Comment: well, I guess they were doing maintenance work, when I tried to post a reply here. hope it goes through this time.
Anyways, I want to give this to someone.
and I want to give him the file or executable which he can install on his machine.
he shouldnt have to start a server or have to do anything at all with mysql.
just want to inform you that I am using node-mysql here. 
I am okay with using electron or node webkit or anything else that can help me convert this to a desktop app.
would love your suggestions on this. thanks

Comment: Ah, in that case, you will have no real difficulty using NWJS for this task. It combines a browser and Node environment all into one. So the app will be it's own server and client.

Comment: so @Ewald, could you tell how to do it? I am not sure how to even do the first step. I have read a lot of articles but it's getting confusing

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work offline, in other words, stand-alone, you'll need to revisit your approach regarding persistence.  MySQL is not something I'd attempt to bundle with the application.  You would ideally use something from the link Yonghoon Lee suggested, as you need the app to have an embedded database instead of an external one.

I've had success doing something similar, although switching to IndexDB meant I had to rewrite all my queries as it's a NoSQL database.  Please resist using Web SQL database, it's not standard and could disappear at any time.

Other than that, I don't see anything that's an obvious problem to convert to a NWJS application. You can refer to [the official documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/) for some examples of how to get started.

Comment: could you give me a step by step breakdown of how to do this?
i have read a lot of articles and it's just getting more and more confusing.
i dont know what to do.

Comment: Might I humbly suggest that you work through the three examples at http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/#write-nwjs-app as it will show you how the NW.js ecosystem works.  They start off with a simple add, then add some NW.js features and, finally, show you how to use Node.js to create your own "embedded" server.  Those are the actual steps you need to take and it will give you a good foundation to get started.  Before you do that, it'll be pointless to continue, because nothing will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot easily be ported. You should not expect the people on stackoverflow to do all the work for you. It is not a simple task but i will try to guide you trough it.

1.) understand what NWJS is. NWJS ist not just a node.js server but also a client. That means you can use both the code of node.js and javascript code that is ment to run on the client.

2.) You server js is not necessary. The entry point of you application is no server js file but an index.html file.

3.) You js code should be added into the  tag of the index html. Her you can create a main.js file with the code you want to run and add it as a script tag.

4.) Install mysql into your nwjs package with `npm install mysql --save`
You have to run this command in the folder that has you `package.json`

5.) If you want to use routes you have to install express.js
The routes will be localhost routes on your computer

Now you have to consider what you really want to do? From where should the routes be accessible? Would you want an app where you have buttons that you can click and then provide data to the mysql database?

If you really have the interest to port it to nwjs you have to understand how nwjs works. I have given you the first steps but without further information I cannot give you more advises.

Wish you the best of luck. If you understand the structure of nwjs it will be easy to port it ;)